# Generalize characterization of upper semicontinous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, metric-spaces, classification

Let $X$ be a metric space and denote $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$

It is easy to show that the following two statements are equivalent:

$(1)$ For any real number $c$, we have $f^{-1}(-\infty,c)$ is open in $X$.

$(2)$ For any $x \in X$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists open neighbourhood $U \ni x$ such that for all $y \in U,$ we have $f(x) + \varepsilon > f(y).$

If $f$ satisfies one of the above statements, then $f$ is said to be upper semicontinous.

If we change $(1)$ from open to $F_{\sigma}$, do we have a similar characterization which involves $\varepsilon$? To be more precise,

> If for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $f^{-1}(-\infty,c)$ is $F_{\sigma}$, then can we obtain a conclusion which is similar to $(2)?$

The problem is that I do not know how to visualize $F_{\sigma}$, hence do not know how to formulate an equivalent statement for it.

EDIT: In this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-08/S0002-9939-00-05826-3/S0002-9939-00-05826-3.pdf), the authors obtained the following theorem:

> For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists positive functions $\delta$ on $X$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $d_X(x,y) < \min \{ \delta(x), \delta(y) \}$ if and only if $f$ is of the first Baire class.

So it seems that we can also have a similar definition of the above function in terms of $\varepsilon.$ However, I couldn't obtain it.

Comment: What does it mean "similar"? (2) cannot stand as it is because it is equivalent to u.s.c., and your condition is not.

Comment: By similar, i mean can we obtain an equivalent statement for the statement 'for any real number $c$, preimage $f^{-1}(-\infty,c)$ is $F_{\sigma} $. Actually I am trying to generalize definition of u.s.c. in terms of $\varepsilon $.

Comment: Does ``to be $F_\sigma$'' mean to be a countable union of closed sets?

Comment: Yes, you are right.